# Can we use 'my mother and my father' instead of 'my father and mother'

Tags: grammaticality

What is the role of 'and' in 'I invited my mother and father'?

In this sentence why can't we use
'my mother and **my** father' instead of 'my father and mother' ?

Comment: What lead you to the assumption that you can't use "my mother and my father"? I consider both of them correct.

Comment: Generally one avoids superfluous repetitions.  My father and mother is as clear as my father and my mother. But you won't hear the latter very often.

Comment: @rogermue - An exception would be in a longer sentence, when there is extra information added about each person. For example: _My father was born in Albania and my mother was born in Sicily._ Although the second "my .. was born" isn't required there, I think you'd find it used quite a bit in that construct.

Answer (score 1):

"And" is a conjunction that combines two phrases (words) into a single grammatical structure, part of the sentence.  In your case it's the **object** of the verb *invited*.

You don't need to repeat "*my*" because when omitted it's *presumed*, that element in the language is called "***ellipsis***".

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you don't need to.

Both

> I invited my mother and father

and

> I invited my mother and my father.

are grammatically correct. But the second `my` doesn't add anything to the sentence and hence is often omitted. In fact, (though it is a bit ambiguous) you might even say

> I invited mother and father.

And people would usually assume that you are talking about you own parents.

Answer (score 0):

Anachor - good answer but maybe not the question being asked. I ignored the "my" and thought it was about "Mother and Father" versus "Father and Mother".

Both are OK. "Mother and Father" is common and implies nothing apart from the relationships. The reverse is less common. I think there would be an implication in modern English that the speaker is rather less fond of his mother than his father.